# How do I control my charts using check boxes?

Tags: vba, excel

Fore-warning, I am teaching myself VBA as I work on this project, so I apologize if my coding is cringe-inducing and makes no sense. I am currently working on an excel chart that graphs four different series of 15 different categories. I would like to be able to make each series hidden on the chart whenever I click the assigned checkbox. Right now I have the four checkboxes next to the graph, one for each series, "2015", "2016", "2017", and "2018". I right-clicked on the first checkbox, "2015", and selected Assign Macro. The macro-name was filled in for my, so I selected edit, and the coding module popped up. So far my code looks like this:

```
Sub CheckBox25_Click()
If Cell("Q30").Value = "False" Then
Chart.Series("2015").Hidden = True
Else:
Chart.Series("2015").Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

*"Q30" is the cell I have linked to the checkbox to display the true/false value.*

**I am aware that "Chart.Series("2015").xxx is not the proper way to call on the sereis. 
If someone could please tell me how to properly call on the series so I can hide it from the chart that would be greatly appreciated. I'm also not sure that ".hidden" is the correct identifier to use, if you could point me in the right direction for that too that would be great.**

Currently I get the "sub or function not defined error" but I believe that is because of my incorrect coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning visibility, the code below simply filters the Chart series, remember to amend the Sheet name and the Chart name too, then do the same for other Series:

```
Sub CheckBox25_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    If ws.Cell("Q30").Value = "False" Then
        ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection("2015").IsFiltered = True
    Else
        ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection("2015").IsFiltered = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting "Method or data member not found", is that because i didn't call a name properly?

Comment: @Zach, yes, did you amend the Sheet name to the name you are using? Also did you change the "Chart 1" to the actual name of your Chart?

Comment: @ Xabier I did, everything looks right to me. If the data for the series resided in a table, would that change anything?

Comment: No that shouldn't make any difference, can you also make sure that your series are named appropriately as in this case "2015", "2016", etc... If not you should also change the series name..

Comment: I have checked all of the above and everything matches